# Create a discount rule for WooCommerce with 50% off on fourth product (the cheapest one)

Tags: woocommerce, price, discount

Hy,

I want to create a discount rule for WooCommerce with 50% discount on fourth product (the cheapest one). So if I have at least 4 products in my cart, I want to have a 50% off on the one with the lowest price.
I tried various plugins, but I couldn't do this with any of them.
Can someone help me?

Thank's in advance!

I tried various plugins, but I couldn't do this with any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the product price in the Cart/Checkout with the woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook.

Here I have an example for [applying a discount for bulk quantities](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-bulk-dynamic-pricing-without-a-plugin/), so let me try to edit it for your custom task:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'bbloomer_fourth_item_half_off', 9999 );
 
function bbloomer_fourth_item_half_off( $cart ) {
 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
 
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
 
    if ( count( $cart->get_cart() ) < 4 ) return; // AT LEAST 4 PRODUCTS

    $min = PHP_FLOAT_MAX;
    $cheapest = '';
 
    // FIND CHEAPEST ITEM
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      if ( $cart_item['data']->get_price() < $min ) {
         $min = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
         $cheapest = $cart_item_key;
      }
    }

    // REDUCE CHEAPEST ITEM PRICE BY 50%
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      if ( $cheapest == $cart_item_key ) {
         $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() / 2;
         $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
      }
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. The code provided by you works, but two problems arise: 1. if I put two pieces of the product with the lowest price, the discount is applied to both pieces, which is not good. I only want to offer a discount on one product. 2. It does not appear anywhere that there is a discount on that product. Is it possible to somehow show the initial cut price? or should an explanation appear somewhere at Cart Totals? Thank you!!

Comment: @Sorin Ok, your description said "4 products" so I guessed you meant "4 distinct products" (e.g. 2 * product A, 3 * product B, 1 * product C, 9 * product D). You meant "4 items" instead (so, 3 * product A and 1 * product B)? Well, that changes everything, including the calculation (in case you have 3 of the same pieces it's 16.6% off instead), because you can only change the price of the product, not the single item. This is unless you [split cart items when product quantity is greater than 1](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-separate-cart-items-product-quantity-1/).

Comment: In regard to _It does not appear anywhere that there is a discount on that product. Is it possible to somehow show the initial cut price? or should an explanation appear somewhere at Cart Totals?_ that would require another code change, where you actually go and set the sale price (so ->set_sale_price()) instead. You can then calculate the total savings and show them as per this tutorial: [WooCommerce: Display Total Discount / Savings @ Cart & Checkout](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-total-discount-savings-cart/)

Comment: 4 distinct products remain, but the offer is for 1 pieces. Ex. if I have Product A - 1 Item, Product B - 1 Item, Product C - 1 Item, Product D - 1 Item, where Product D is the cheapest, I want to apply 50% of Product D for 1 item. If I have Product D - 2 items, only 1 item will be with 50% off, the other one will have the full price.

Comment: _If I have Product D - 2 items, only 1 item will be with 50% off, the other one will have the full price._ exactly, so in that case you need to apply 50%/2 off = 25% because you have quantity 2. You can only target both products, and therefore need to recalculate the discount, unless, once again you split the cart items

Comment: How can I do this with your code?